# CompleteableFuture for a large dataset

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have multi-threaded Spring Boot application in which I am reading data from table in batches (the table contains around 1 million records).

I am getting into Java heap memory issues, and I am unable to find a workaround. Below is the code sample.

I call the Spring Boot REST API which then calls this code. Here I am reading from db in the main thread in batches, then passing the batches to thread pool `executorService` and then finally processing the result in another thread pool `resultProcessor`.

The `Worker` class `implements Callable<WorkerResult>`

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    Long workerCount = 0L;
    ExecutorService resultProcessor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<CompletableFuture<WorkerResult>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    while (workerCount < totalData) {

        List<Model> dbRecords = repo.getData(workerCount,workerCount+rp,date);
        workerCount += rp + 1;

        try {
                futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        return new Worker(dbRecords).call(); // Here for each record third party api is called
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new CompletionException(ex);
                    }
                    // Or return default value
                }, executorService).thenApplyAsync(result -> {

                    service.resultReceived(result); // update the results into db
                    return result;
                }, resultProcessor));
            

        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            logData("Can't submit anymore tasks  %s ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Outside the while loop once I have read all data from DB, then I call the `CompletableFuture.allOf` method to finish any remaining tasks.
Below is the code for that:

```
try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    resultProcessor.shutdown();
    resultProcessor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here, if I do not add the `CompletableFuture.allOf`, the result is returned from this method without completing all tasks in the queues.

Instead of calling `CompletableFuture.allOf`, I have tried `futures.foreach(CompletableFuture::join)` but my issue didn't resolve that way either.

Currently, I have assigned 1GB ram to the Tomcat server, therefore I face heap space error after some 100 thousand records are processed successfully.

What can I do here to get rid of this error and improve code efficiency as well, also the solution should be in Java 8 and not the latest versions if possible.

I don't know how much data will be in real this is a test environment data.

Comment: Your `Worker` class looks like a _task_, and your `workerCount` looks like the number of tasks that have been submitted to the thread pool. A task is not the same thing as a worker. We usually say "worker" when we are talking about the threads that belong to the pool. Each worker performs many tasks in a typical thread pool use-case.

Comment: What is the point of "reading data...in batches?" Your loop doesn't appear to do the actual work in batches. It looks like you first submit the entire one million tasks to the pool, and then you wait for all of them to be completed. Depending on the relative speed of processing the records vs. retrieving the records, and depending on the structure of code you haven't shown to us, you may have up to the whole one million records in memory at the same time, and you certainly will have the whole one million results in memory at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow workerCount var is used as on offset for picking data from DB, I agree its poorly named. 
The number of threads are set to 15 when the initial task is being sent, its result is processed in another thread pool  whose thread count is 10

Comment: @SolomonSlow No, I read data in batches lets say I read 5k records each time and then that array is  supplied to the 'supplyAsync' method which will be processed in a thread pool.

The loop is working on the main thread as soon as the count reaches to totalData it exists goes to next code snippet where i call the shutDown methods of the executor services

Comment: So, are you  saying that `totalData` is 5K, and not one million? `totalData` is how many results will be in memory at the same time, and it's the upper bound on how many records might be in memory at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow TotalData is 1Million whereas workerCount starts from 0 and then after each iteration 5k is added to it and it stops when it reaches to 1Million by that time alot of data is already processed by threads but I get heap memory error as I save results in a list. I do that to call the Completeable future join method to process any remaining tasks

Comment: Actually, Why are you using `CompletableFuture` at all? You're building a list of 1,000,000 results, and then you want to create an array of those results, but where do you actually ever _use_ the results? If I were trying to solve your problem, I would use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that was constructed with a fixed-size `ArrayBlockingQueue` for its task queue, and I would submit plain `Runnable` tasks to it. Because the queue is bounded, that would prevent the database reader thread from out-pacing the worker threads, and it would limit your heap usage.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I need to `CompleteableFuture` because I want to process in parallel everything, like read from DB in main thread, then process in the thread pools.

Actually You are right I didn't need to store the results, After removing `futures.add` and then just finally calling the `shutdown` method resolved the memory issue and it didnt even skipped the tasks pending in the thread pools, as I was thinking.
`ExecutorService` FixedThreadPool create live thread and not daemon threads, so the program does not exits untill all tasks are finished.
Thanks for the help.